# Differentiating paid vs. organic search in yahoo referer URL

Tags: search, header, analytics

We're trying to separate organic from paid search in our sales data by looking a the full referer URL in our HTTP request headers.

This is possible for Google by noting referer subdomains like pagead2.googlesyndication.com or directories in the URL like aclk.

But is there anything to differentiate organic vs. paid via the referer URLs for Yahoo traffic? What about Bing?